# How to plot barchat with multiple bars with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, seaborn

I want to plot barchart with data cannot figure out how to plot with seaborn barplot with several bars (i.e. I want on **x** *ax* 'referee_id' and 3 bar for each showing won/draw/lost, the **y** *ax* - quantities) with such DataFrame:

[image: t]

As plotting with sns.barplot(), it stacks/layers all quantities.

My code:

```
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
subplot = figure.add_subplot()
sns.barplot(all_referees['Field_referee_id'],all_referees['Quantity_lost'],  color="tomato", label = "lost")
sns.barplot(all_referees['Field_referee_id'],all_referees['Quantity_draw'],  color="yellow", label = "draw")
sns.barplot(all_referees['Field_referee_id'],all_referees['Quantity_won'],  color="limegreen", label = "won")
for item in subplot.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)
plt.xticks(ha='right',fontweight='light',fontsize='large')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=False)
```

And moreover:

- how to make condition to show only referees who judged at least 7 games (lost+draw+won >=7) ?
- how to make width gap between each referee`s 3-bars ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to re-shape your dataframe from wide to long.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': list('abcd'), 'Quantity_Lost':[3,5,3,4], 'Quantity_Draw':[2,2,1,None], 'Quantity_Won': [5,1,4,2]})
#  ID  Quantity_Lost  Quantity_Draw  Quantity_Won
#0  a              3            2.0             5
#1  b              5            2.0             1
#2  c              3            1.0             4
#3  d              4            NaN             2
df1 = df[df.filter(regex='Quantity_').sum(axis=1).ge(7)]
df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df1, stubnames=['Quantity'], i='ID', j='Result', sep='_', suffix='.*')
sns.barplot(x='ID', y='Quantity', hue='Result', data=df1.reset_index(), palette=['tomato','yellow','limegreen'])
```

[image]

---

It's much easier, however, to use pandas for plotting:

```
df[df.filter(regex='Quantity_').sum(axis=1).ge(7)].plot.bar(color=['tomato','yellow','limegreen'])
```